# How to run join query on multiple tables ?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

This is my table structure 
I have 3 tables:

1. member table
2. comments table
3. comments like table

The tables structures can be found in the following images:

Table: member

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
user_id |full_name |email   | password  | image     |join_date     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table: album_comments

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
id |album_id |comment_text | comment_userid | post_date |active_bit|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table: comment_likes

```
-------------------------------------------------------
id |user_id  |comment_id   | post_date      | like_bit|   
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to join three tables and retrieve the result. Here is what I need:

I want to return latest 20 comments and check if the member who is currently logged in has liked any of the comment in these 20 comments. If yes then return status bit as 1 for those comments and if not then return status bit 0.

Can anyone tell what would be the SQL query for this?

Comment: Did you write any code? We can help you as long you help yourself !

Answer (score 0):

this will give you latest 20 comments:

```
SELECT ac.comment_text FROM album_comments ac
ORDER BY ac.post_date DESC LIMIT 20
```

you need to explain in which manner the data is inserting in your comment_likes table..plz let me know and also you need to do some conditional coding in your code to matching a particular user likes..

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @currently_logged_userid int = 0;

select top 20 ac.comment_text, isnull(cl.like_bit,0)
from album_comments ac
   left join comment_likes cl on ac.id = cl.comment_id
where ac.comment_userid = @currently_logged_userid       
order by ac.post_date desc
```